# social media share count for each individual user registered

Tags: php, count

I had used "AddToAny" for social media count and share of each coupon separately with different url,image,title.

Here is the code i used to share and count with respect to coupon

```
<a class="a2a_button_facebook a2a_counter" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=&t=" title="Share on Facebook" rel="tooltip" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?app_id=1408715659177606s=100&p[url]=<?php echo $url?>/couponDetails.php?coupid=<?php echo $couponoffers_rows['DB_CM_CID']?>&p[images][0]=<?php echo $logo?>&p[title]=<?php echo $couponoffers_rows['TITLE'] ?>&p[summary]=<?php echo $couponoffers_rows['DESCRIPTION']?>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=450,height=298'); return false; "></a>

<a class="a2a_button_pinterest a2a_counter" data-url="<?php echo $url?>/couponDetails.php?coupid=<?php echo $couponoffers_rows['DB_CM_CID']?>" data-media="<?php echo $logo?>" data-description="<?php echo $couponoffers_rows['TITLE']?>"       rel="tooltip" title="share on pinterest" target="_blank"></a>

<a class="a2a_button_google_plusone a2a_counter" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo $url?>/couponDetails.php?coupid=<?php echo $couponoffers_rows['DB_CM_CID']?>"  rel="tooltip" title="share on google-plus" target="_blank"  onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600'); return false; " data-media="<?php echo $logo?>" ></a> 

<a  class="a2a_button_twitter a2a_counter" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=" onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=<?php echo $url?>/couponDetails.php?coupid=<?php echo $couponoffers_rows['DB_CM_CID']?>', 'twitterwindow', 'height=450, width=550, top=' + ($(window).height() / 2 - 225) + ', left=' + $(window).width() / 2 + ', toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=0');" data-media="<?php echo $logo?>" rel="tooltip" title="share on twitter" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i></a>
```

But how do i count to each individual who logged in and when they share on different social media sites.

Comment: You need to check each social media's API's documentation to see how/if you can do something like that. All services work different. The question is currently too broad.

Comment: Here is my code https://pastebin.com/VB2Nne7r  But still it is not giving the exact count. Please help me out with this

Comment: Don't post links to code on third party sites. All code should be posted in the question. You need to edit your question to; 1. Include all relevant code. 2. Describe the issue with the expected result and what result you're currently getting.Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)